# Add supervisor in php:7-fpm image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I use the php:7-fpm image, and I would like install and use Supervisor, to run some PHP script in background (rabbitmq workers).

I can easily install supervisor, create the conf file and add it in the image. But, I don't know how to do for launch it at the container start. If I replace que CMD with supervisor, then php-fpm don't start. At the end of the php-fpm dockerfile in the docker library, they use `CMD ["php-fpm"]`, I've try to add it in my supervisor conf, and use `CMD /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`, it start supervisor, and a simple php service. But it don't work.

Can we use many CMD ? Or are there any simple solution ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.5-fpm

############################
# Install PHP requirements #
############################

# Install wget, git and libraries needed by php extensions
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    zlib1g-dev \
    wget \
    git \
    supervisor

# Remove lists
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Compile ICU (required by intl php extension)
RUN curl -sS -o /tmp/icu.tar.gz -L http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/58.2/icu4c-58_2-src.tgz && \
    tar -zxf /tmp/icu.tar.gz -C /tmp && \
    cd /tmp/icu/source && \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && \
    make && \
    make install

# Configure, install and enable php extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl --with-icu-dir=/usr/local
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl pdo pdo_mysql zip bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-enable opcache

# Install Composer
RUN php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

# Copy the php.ini file
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

##################
# Define workdir #
##################
WORKDIR /var/www/html/current
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
php:
    container_name: php
    build: ./docker/php
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html/current:rw
        - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
        - ./docker/php/supervisor/blast_consumer.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/blast_consumer.conf:ro
    networks:
        - default
```

My blast_consumer:

```
[program:php-fpm]
command=/usr/sbin/php-fpm
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/php-fpm_consumer.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/php-fpm_consumer.out.log
priority=100

[program:blast_consumer]
command=/var/www/html/current/bin/console rabbitmq:consumer blast
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/blast_consumer.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/blast_consumer.out.log
priority=200
```

Comment: Your configurations looks ok. What's the container output?

Comment: Like it the container work, but supervisor is not running in. Because I don't start it in Dockerfile. But, if I start supervisor, php don't start...

Comment: any solution to start up the 2 of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that php-fpm is located at `/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm`. So update your supervisor `command` accordingly:

```
[program:php-fpm]
command=/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/php-fpm_consumer.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/php-fpm_consumer.out.log
priority=100

[program:blast_consumer]
command=/var/www/html/current/bin/console rabbitmq:consumer blast
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/blast_consumer.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/blast_consumer.out.log
priority=200
```

To have further information of your supervisor, do this inside container:

```
supervisorctl status
supervisorctl tail php-fpm
```

Comment: thank you for this! Answered my question/problem as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running an Ubuntu or any other Debian-based machine, your fpm file is located at here:

```
/usr/sbin/php-fpm8.1
```